# grunt-wiredep doesn't injecting js libs with dot in lib folder name

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-wiredep

grunt-wiredep while executing

> grunt wiredep:target

task returns:

```
leaflet.markercluster was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "/home/rd/java/workspace/test-express/bower_components/leaflet.markercluster" for the file you need, then manually include it in your file.
```

Same behaviour is for other libs with dots in folder name. Other libs are injected correctly to hmtl and jade files. Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this other than manually adding the files?

Comment: No, other folders with dot are still need to be added manually using wiredep. My solution was to put manually added libs outside of bower:js tag.

Comment: Are you using windows or mac to program on?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.1.

Comment: @RadoslawDardzinski - dou you got solution for it??

Comment: @Chetan I posted my solution in comment. Haven't found any other.

Comment: @RadoslawDardzinski - found the solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263475/gulp-and-wire-dep-not-injecting-file-type-js-files